# Selected autocomplete value not displaying in input box

Tags: php, laravel, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery ui autocomplete and the values were displaying but when i select a value from the list it is not displaying inside the input box.. I used console.log for select : function , the selected value is displayed in console but not inside the input box,

I have attached a screenshot of the issue,

[image]

Here i have selected 24 and it is displaying in console but not coming inside the input box (i.e, box attached with Lot Number label)..

The script was,

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var lot_selection = {!! $lot_selection !!};
        $("#lot_number").autocomplete({
            autoFocus: true,
            source: lot_selection,
            minLength: 0,
            select: function (event, ui) {

                 $('#lot_number').val(ui.item.lot_number);
                 console.log($('#lot_number'), ui.item.lot_number);
            }
        })
        .focus(function () {
            $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
        })
        .data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li>")
                    .append("<a>" + item.lot_number + "</a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
        };
    });

</script>
```

And the laravel lot_number input form code was,

```
<div class="col-md-2 hidden-print">
    <div class="input-group">
        {!! Form::input('text', 'lot_number', null, array('id' => 'lot_number', 'class' => 'input-lg form-control TabOnEnter', 'placeholder' => 'lot_number','autofocus', 'tabindex' => 1)) !!}
        <span class="input-group-addon">Lot Number</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select: function (event, ui) {
              event.preventDefault();  
             $('#lot_number').val(ui.item.lot_number);
             console.log($('#lot_number'), ui.item.lot_number);
        }
```

Change your select function as like above

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var lot_selection = {!! $lot_selection !!};
        $("#lot_number").autocomplete({
            autoFocus: true,
            source: lot_selection,
            minLength: 0,
            select: function (event, ui) {

                 $('#lot_number').val(ui.item.lot_number);
                 console.log($('#lot_number'), ui.item.lot_number);
            }
            focus: function(event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#lot_number").val(ui.item.lot_number);
            }
        })
        .focus(function () {
            $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
        })
        .data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $("<li>")
                    .append("<a>" + item.lot_number + "</a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
        };
    });

</script>
```

Try this code it will help...

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!